# How to put in new disk in a MegaRAID SAS 2108 HW RAID card?

Tags: raid5

It's in RAID5, we already have 4 disk in it. 1 is a spare.

```
01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
```

with 4 disks.

**Question:** How can we put in additional storage to it? After a new disk is attached to the HW card, what are the steps so that the OS will recognize it?

Comment: What did you use to put the orginal disk on that? Hardware RAID. `mdadm`?

Comment: it's not a sw RAID, it's a HW RAID.

Comment: This site provides binaries for hardware RAID controllers: http://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS Can't tell you though which one you need, and how exactly to use it... I used such a tool only once, and all I remember that it was extremely complicated ^^